# Rapid compression of multiple lists with value addition

Tags: python, list, compression, indices

I am looking for a pythonic way to iterate through a large number of lists and use the index of repeated values from one list to calculate a total value from the values with the same index in another list.

For example, say I have two lists

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
b = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

What I want to do is find the unique values in a, and then add together the corresponding values from b with the same index. My attempt, which is quite slow, is as follows:

```
a1=list(set(a))
b1=[0 for y in range(len(a1))] 
    for m in range(len(a)):
        for k in range(len(a1)):
            if a1[k]==a[m]:
                b1[k]+=b[m]
```

and I get

```
a1=[1, 2, 3]
b1=[12, 15, 18]
```

Please let me know if there is a faster, more pythonic way to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and a [`defaultdict` dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to collect values per unique value:

```
from collections import defaultdict
try:
    # Python 2 compatibility
    from future_builtins import zip
except ImportError:
    # Python 3, already there
    pass

values = defaultdict(int)
for key, value in zip(a, b):
    values[key] += value

a1, b1 = zip(*sorted(values.items()))
```

`zip()` pairs up the values from your two input lists, now all you have to do is sum up each value from `b` per unique value of `a`.

The last line pulls out the keys and values from the resulting dictionary, sorts these, and puts just the keys and just the values into `a1` and `b1`, respectively.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> a = [ 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> values = defaultdict(int)
>>> for key, value in zip(a, b):
...     values[key] += value
...
>>> zip(*sorted(values.items()))
[(1, 2, 3), (12, 15, 18)]
```

If you don't care about output order, you can drop the `sorted()` call altogether.

Comment: This seems to work great! I was wondering if would be possible to add another level of complexity to this. That is, a third list, say c=[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0], so that the value is only added when c[key]=1??

Comment: @MicahJ: just add `c` to the first `zip()`: `for key, value, add in zip(a, b, c):`, then insert an `if add:` in between.